# Is there an analogue of "ngIf" directive in NativeScript without Angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-template, angular2-nativescript, angular-ng-if

In Angular, we can use *ngIf directive in the template in case if we want to create/remove (also show/hide) dom element.

Is there an analog of "ngIf" directive in NativeScript without Angular?

Comment: `*ngIf` is an angular thing, hence the `ng`

Comment: I know that *ngIf is an angular thing. That's why I'm asking "Is there an ANALOG of ngIf directive in NativeScript without Angular?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NativeScript* supports the *"collapsed"* and *"visible"* states of the CSS visibility property.
This means you can hide an element by setting its *"visibility"* property to *"collapsed"* in CSS.

And you can conditionally change its property which will be (near about) same as angular's `ngIf` condition.

```
   visibility="{{ showTextDetails ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"
```

Hope this help!

Comment: thank you for the reply! I think it's the most optimal solution.